# Random Forest Error in na.fail.default: missing values in object

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, feature-selection

I am running an RF model, which runs with no errors with most variables; however, when I include one variable: duration_in_program, and the following code:

````
```{r Random Forest Model}
## Run a Random Forest model
mod_rf <-
  train(left_school ~ job_title 
        + gender + 
        + marital_status + age_at_enrollment + monthly_wage + educational_qualification + cityD + educational_qualification + cityC.
        + cityB +cityA + duration_in_program, # Equation (outcome and everything else)
        data=train_data, # Training data 
        method = "ranger", # random forest (ranger is much faster than rf)
        metric = "ROC", # area under the curve
        trControl = control_conditions,
        tuneGrid = tune_mtry
  )
mod_rf
````

I get the following error:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(left_welfare = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, : missing values in object
```

Comment: Have you confirmed there are now missing values in duration_in_program? Also, what package is `train()` in? I'm used to using `randomForest()`.

Comment: Nevermind, saw you tagged it with r-caret, so I assumed that was it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `train()` is from caret, you can specify a function to handle na's with the `na.action` parameter. The default is `na.fail`. A very common one is `na.omit`. The randomForest library has `na.roughfix` that will "Impute Missing Values by median/mode."

```r
mod_rf <-
  train(left_school ~ job_title 
        + gender + 
        + marital_status + age_at_enrollment + monthly_wage + educational_qualification + cityD + educational_qualification + cityC.
        + cityB +cityA + duration_in_program, # Equation (outcome and everything else)
        data=train_data, # Training data 
        method = "ranger", # random forest (ranger is much faster than rf)
        metric = "ROC", # area under the curve
        trControl = control_conditions,
        tuneGrid = tune_mtry,
        na.action = na.omit
  )
mod_rf
```